# How to change the resolution of .tif raster file without losing data

Tags: python, gis, tiff, raster, qgis

For example, A .tiff file of 400*200 size, I can read it as a 2-D array(400 x 200) in python.

I want to change the tiff size to 200 x 100 or other ratio.

How to realize that in Python or GIS software(QGIS, ArcGIS et.al).

I know the **resemble** tool in ArcGIS can change the size of raster data. but the length-width ratio is fixed.

Example Diagram:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tietuku.com](http://i12.tietuku.com/b0841a1ceb25729a.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With R you can do things like

```
library(raster)
r <- raster('file.tif')
a <- aggregate(r, c(2,3))
```